# What's the KVC path for summing UIView subview properties?

Tags: cocoa, uiscrollview, key-value-coding

I'm trying to calculate the total height of subviews in a UIScrollView:

```
[self.subviews valueForKeyPath:@"bounds.size.@sum.height"];
```

But that throws the following:

```
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSConcreteValue 0x4b10170> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key size.'
```

I've tried placing the `@sum` operator in various places in that path, all with the same result.

Of course I could just do this with a loop, but I'm specifically curious about the KVC solution -- I assume it's possible and I'm just doing it wrong. What's the proper path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible. `size` is a property in the `CGRect` struct, not some property of some class (same yields for `height`). You can't retrieve these values using KVC, since `bounds` is not an object, just a struct.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, but not directly (See @JoostK's answer for why).  Here's how I would do it:

Create a `UIView` category that adds a method, like this:

```
@interface UIView (KVCAdditions)

- (CGFloat) boundsHeight;

@end

@implementation UIView (KVCAdditions)

- (CGFloat) boundsHeight {
  return [self bounds].size.height;
}

@end
```

Now you should be able to do this:

```
NSNumber * totalHeight = [[self subviews] valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.boundsHeight"];
```

Comment: Smart way to do it, but not the method of my choice. Adding a method just to be able to use KVC for a simple summation does not make sense for me. Neat illustration of the possibility though.